# Facebook Graph apprequest JSON response

Tags: facebook-graph-api, cordova, sencha-touch-2

Getting an invalid JSON response using the [Phonegap FB integration](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) + Sencha Touch:

> {"request":"12345678","to%5B0%5D":"12345678"}

Looks like some botched encoding trying to return the 'to' array.

```
    FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: (msg) ? msg : 'Start using MyApp',
        display: 'touch'
    }, 
    function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));  
        if(response) {

        } else {
            console.log('Error parsing FB request response');
        }
    });
```

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

After trying a couple different short-term patches, I settled on a simple iterating of the object to parse out the userIds. Posting in case this helps somebody to get moving until there's a fix.

```
    response.to = [];
    for(var prop in response){
        if(prop != 'request'){
            response.to.push(response[prop]);
        }               
    }
```